# Pause Backgroundworker until user Confirm Cancellation

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am uploading an excel file into database. Below are the steps: 
1. I have the excel data in excelRawData (DataTable)
2. UploadProgress is the ProgressBar

```
            int insertWkSuccess = 0;
            bool wait = true;
            int progress = 0;
            uploadProgress.Visible = lblPercent.Visible = true;
            btnCancel.Text = "Cancel Upload";
            uploadProgress.Value = 0;
            uploadProgress.Maximum = excelRawData.Rows.Count;
            _workerUpload = null;
            _workerUpload = new BackgroundWorker();
            rtxtError.AppendText("Uploading Sheet Data.........\n");
            _workerUpload.DoWork += (obj, args) =>
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in excelRawData.Rows)
                {
                    if (wait)
                    {
                        if (_workerUpload.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            args.Cancel = true;
                            args.Result = null;
                            return;
                        }

                        if (upload.Upload(row, excelRawData.Rows.IndexOf(row) + 1, country, company, version, ref errorMsg))
                            insertWkSuccess++;
                        progress++;
                        if (_workerUpload == null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        _workerUpload.ReportProgress(progress);
                        setPercentValue((progress*100)/uploadProgress.Maximum);
                    }
                    if (errorMsg.Count() == 0 && insertWkSuccess > 0)
                    {
                        upload.insertWktoMain(version, country, ref errorMsg);
                    }
                    args.Result = new object[] { insertWkSuccess, company, selectedSheet };
                }
            };
            _workerUpload.ProgressChanged+=_workerUpload_ProgressChanged;
            _workerUpload.RunWorkerCompleted+=_workerUpload_RunWorkerCompleted;
            _workerUpload.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            _workerUpload.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            _workerUpload.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Below is my Coding for Cancel button click.

```
     if (_workerUpload.IsBusy)
            {
                wait = false;
                var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to terminate the current upload process.",
                                 "Confirm Stop Process!!",
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                if (confirmResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    wait = true;
                    _workerUpload.CancelAsync();
                }
                else
                    wait = true;
            }
```

The problem here is that, When I wait for the Cancel Confirmation Dialog box result, the upload process still continues in the background. Is there a way to stop the background process until the result of the dialog box is obtained.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, what's the purported benefit here? They accidentally hit the cancel button as they e.g. lock their machine and walk away for 10 minutes. They come back, unlock their machines, see the dialog and say "heck, no" and click the `No` button. (Or simpler scenarios where they, for whatever reason, choose "No"). What's the benefit of doing no useful work whilst waiting for their negative response? If you're so sure they'll answer "Yes", why prompt at all?

Comment: There is for sure a way - but why do you want to pause it? Stop it, when the user is very sure he really wants to cancel.

Comment: Like everyone said there is no point in asking the user _Are you sure to stop the upload process_ when the code has already stopped it. The behavior in the current form will be more appropriate.

Comment: I am trying to cancel after confirmation. Is it possible using backgroundworker ?

Comment: Sometimes, less is more. What happens if the user accidentally cancels upload? He starts it again. So what? Nothing lost (apart from some time). On the other hand if he needs to confirm: He saw he uploads the wrong file. The one that is super confidential ... he wants to cancel _now_.

Comment: A *bool* is a pretty lousy synchronization object.  Use ManualResetEventSlim instead.  Now you can simply use WaitOne() in your worker and it will actually wait.